# How to store multiple columns in 1 column as value in sql

Tags: sql-server

How can I get all the columns from a subquery and store it in 1 column? I need it to be in 1 column to be used as a series in chart.

Here's my code:

```
Select A,B,C,D,E,F as newcol from 
(SELECT 
COUNT(NULLIF(A,'')) as A,
COUNT(NULLIF(B,'')) as B,
COUNT(NULLIF(C,'')) as C,
COUNT(NULLIF(D,'')) as D,
COUNT(NULLIF(E,'')) as E,
COUNT(NULLIF(F,'')) as F
FROM MYTABLE)
as T
```

Since the subquery result is in a form of 1 row. I needed the A,B,C,D,E,F as column values to be used as series values in my chart. I wanted to show the count of each columns(ABCDEF) in a graph form.(Instead of 1 row with 6 columns, I want result in 1 column with 6 rows)

Comment: Are you asking how to pivot your data here? So, instead of 1 row with 6 columns, you want 1 column with 6 rows?

Comment: Or really... [unpivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @Larnu yes. The code I posted gives a result like this:

A | B | C | D | E | F
1 | 2  | 2 | 3  | 2  | 1

so it's 1 row with multiple columns. I need it to be 1 column with multiple rows because I'll be using it to my bar chart where the x values is the column names and the y values as the count.

Comment: Have you looked at either of the answers here @meandyou ? The comments are not the place to supply sample and expected data; it should be in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this:

```
Select A,B,C,D,E,F as newcol from
```

I suppose you want all the columns concatenated to 1 column, like this:

```
Select concat(A, ',', B, ',', C, ',', D, ',', E, ',', F) as newcol from
```

If you want just 1 column where each value is 1 row, then you already have the values in your select statement and can be combined with UNION ALL:

```
SELECT COUNT(NULLIF(A,'')) as newcol FROM MYTABLE
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(NULLIF(B,'')) FROM MYTABLE
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(NULLIF(C,'')) FROM MYTABLE
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(NULLIF(D,'')) FROM MYTABLE
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(NULLIF(E,'')) FROM MYTABLE
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(NULLIF(F,'')) FROM MYTABLE
```

Comment: Hi! The union all is the closest yet I would like the Column names to be the one which are stacked in one column with multiple row

Comment: I don't think I understand that `I would like the Column names to be the one which are stacked in one column`. Can you post sample data and expected results?

Comment: The code I posted gives a result like this: https://snag.gy/mIGLWx.jpg

so it's 1 row with multiple columns. I need it to be 1 column with multiple rows because I'll be using it to my bar chart where the x values is the column names and the y values as the count. Is it possible? I'm sorry, I'm still a newbie.

Comment: This is exactly what UNION ALL does. 1 column with 1 value in each row

Comment: I got it! I just added one more column in the union code you've given. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply wanting the pivot your data and `MYTABLE` really does only have one row, the simpliest way would seem to be:

```
SELECT V.YourColum
FROM MYTABLE T
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(T.A),
                        (T.B),
                        (T.C),
                        (T.D),
                        (T.E),
                        (T.F)) V(YourColumn);
```

This **assumes** all the columns have the same datatype.